uso de localStorage para mantenerse en el ultimo tab al refrescar la pagina
Hola a todos estoy leyendo un poco sobre localStorage pero la verdad no sabría como implementarlo, al usar tabs o pestañas y al refrescar la pagina siempre se regresa a la primera. y si lo he entendido poco se que localStorage guarda la ultima tab pero como guardo y utilizo ese nombre al momento de refrescar quedar en la misma tab en la que estaba.. alguna idea por favor mil gracias.. puse en el codigo alert para ver si imprimia el nombre del botón pulsado pero no eso no resulta!!!
<button class="tablinks"
  onclick="openCity(event, 'daily')"
  id="daily">Journalier</button>
<button class="tablinks"
  onclick="openCity(event, 'hourly')"
  id="hourly">Horaire</button>
<button class="tablinks"
  onclick="openCity(event, 'Exdaily')"
  id="Exdaily">Excel journalier</button>
<button class="tablinks"
  onclick="openCity(event, 'Exhourly')"
  id="Exhourly">Excel Horaire</button>
<script>
  window.onload = function () {
    const activeTab = localStorage.getItem("activeTab");
    if(activeTab){
      alert (activeTab);
    }
  }
</script>


Antes de hacer un getItem debes hacer un setItem para guardar el dato activo. localStorage tan solo guarda/recupera pares de claves/valores, luego eres tu quien usa los valores que se guardan/recuperan como desees.  En tu caso, tal como tienes ahora el código, no te sirve de nada.  Primero debes diferenciar cada pestaña de forma única, ya sea con un ID o con una clase única, y luego, mediante javascript, cazar el evento de la pulsación en cada pestaña para que vaya actualizando el localStorage de la clave deseada, que segun parece vas a usar una denominada "activeTab"

Y finalmente, debes poner un código javascript para que al recargar/cargar la página, mire si existe la clave "activeTab" y que valor tiene, y entonces poner la clase "active" en dicha pestaña para que te aparezca como activa.  Inténtalo, y actualiza la pregunta con lo que hayas probado, pues ahora mismo aún no has hecho nada y se trata de que lo practiques y aprendas, no que te lo hagamos aquí de forma completa.

Seguramente puedes meter el localStorage.setItem al inicio de la función openCity, y con eso casi que ya lo tienes, pues veo que efectivamente si que usas id diferenciados, y puedes usarlos como valor de la clave activeTab que quieres usar.

Para realizar dicha acción, en el localStorage tienes que guardar el valor de activeTab.

Solución 
Utiliza localStorage.setItem() para guardar el valor de activeTab.
Ejemplo
    <button class="tablinks"
     onclick="openCity(event, 'daily'); localStorage.setItem('activeTab', 0)"
     id="daily">Journalier</button>
    <button class="tablinks"
      onclick="openCity(event, 'hourly'); localStorage.setItem('activeTab', 1)"
     id="hourly">Horaire</button>
    <button class="tablinks"
      onclick="openCity(event, 'Exdaily'); localStorage.setItem('activeTab', 2)"
     id="Exdaily">Excel journalier</button>
   <button class="tablinks"
       onclick="openCity(event, 'Exhourly'); localStorate.setItem('activeTab', 3)"
     id="Exhourly">Excel Horaire</button>
     <script>
     window.onload = function () {
         const activeTab = 
   localStorage.getItem("activeTab");
      if(activeTab){
        alert (activeTab);
         }
    }
  </script>

En este ejemplo utilicé números, pero los puedes cambiar por una str de, como por ejemplo, el nombre de la pestaña.
